# Proof for D'alembert's solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation

[image]

I am totally clueless in how to go about the solution for part iii). I was able to answer the others. Normally I would find the derivatives then substitute. In regards to the initial conditions I'm lost. Someone please explain how I could go about the solution.

Comment: Are you familiar with d'Alembert's solution to the wave equation? If you google this it should get you started on finding the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Are $F$ and $F_x$ continuous? By superposition, it suffices to show that $$v(x,t) = \frac{1}{2c} \int_{0}^{t} \int_{x-c(t-\tau)}^{x+c(t-\tau)} F(\xi, \tau) d\xi d\tau$$ satisfies the given equation and homogeneous versions of the initial condition. For more info see below:

---

From Pinchover and Rubinstein:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]